# For people, can you say "a British" like you can say "an Australian"?

Tags: nouns, adjectives, demonyms

According to Wiktionary, you can't use "a [British](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/British)" to refer to individual British people, though you can use it to refer to a race of people as a whole, but you can use "an [Australian](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Australian)", and this matches what I already suspect.

I can't think of a good Google Ngram query to confirm this.

Is this the case? And if so, why is there a difference?

Comment: People do use "a Brit" (or I've heard "a Briton") but not "a British".

Comment: You can say a *Briton*. In the movies (*Lawrence of Arabia* in particular) you hear Arabs calling Brits *English*, as in "Hey, English, do you know how to ride a camel?", but that's not standard.

Comment: Related:  http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/25289/is-it-appropriate-to-call-a-british-person-a-brit/25292

Comment: An Australian would refer to an individual British person as "a pom". Problem bloody solved!

Comment: @Fortiter or [Bruce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bruces_sketch).

Comment: @Fortiter - not 'a whingeing Pom' then? A step forward in international relations!

Comment: Found this online "USAer and UKer to OZ (one day)!" http://www.pomsinoz.com/forum/welcome/148321-usaer-uker-oz-one-day.html

Comment: Re Lawrence of Arabia. Prior to roughly the mid-20th century Britain was widely referred to around the world as 'England'. And British people would often describe themselves as 'English'. Sensitivity to the idea that Scotland, Ireland are Wales were equivalents of England did not gain wide currency until well into the 20th century. Across Europe, it is still the case that French, Germans, and Italians will speak of 'the English' - *les Anglais* - both in expressions of admiration and disgust.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Those of us who live in these offshore islands often have some difficulty in describing ourselves. We can say that we’re British (although some residents of Northern Ireland may have a problem with that), but there’s no ready equivalent of the sentence *She’s an Australian*. *She’s a Briton* is just about possible, but sounds contrived. *Britisher* might also be found, particularly in films about WWII, but it’s not current.

The difficulty arises because *British* is an adjective, and only an adjective. Like certain other adjectives it can be used as the head of a noun phrase in some contexts. ‘The adjective-headed noun phrase usually refers to a group of people with the characteristic described by the adjective . . . The definite article is typically used with adjectives as noun phrase heads’ (‘Longman Student Grammar of Spoken and Written English’). This means that we can speak of *the British*, just as we can speak of *the elderly* and *the poor*, but we can no more speak of **a British* than we can speak of **an elderly* or **a poor*.

Comment: The same pattern can be seen with _Spanish_, _Swedish_, _Danish_ etc versus _German_, _Italian_, _European_ and so on.

Comment: @MrLister Spaniards, Swedes, and Danes have no such trouble — nor, historically, did Englishmen.

Comment: I didn't try to say there was trouble... just pointing out that there's a pattern to see here beyond _British_ vs _Australian_.

Comment: @Mr Lister. Quite right. Why there should be this difference between nationalities, I do not know.

Comment: @tchrist. _Englishmen_ only ever described roughly half the population of England.

Comment: @BarrieEngland So you’re saying that the men made up the *rougher half* of the populace? I’m sure the fairer sex would have no disagreement with you on that. :)

Comment: Isn't a general restriction on words in _-ish_, as opposed to (eg) words in _-ian_?

Comment: @Colin Fine. Yes, perhaps that's it. _-ish_ words are always adjectives, and only adjectives?

Comment: I can't think of a counterexample.

Answer (score 4):

You can't say *a British*: *British* is an adjectival, *Briton* is the demonym.

The demonym describes the person from a place. So:

1. *The Briton is cheeky.* (noun)

The adjectival can be used as an adjectival noun, or an adjective:

1. *The British are cheeky.* (adj. noun)
2. *The British vase is bronze.* (adj)
3. *The Chinese vase is made of porcelain; the British, of steel.* (adj, then adj. noun)

Usually adjectivals and demonyms are the same, but there are exceptions.

*-ish* adjectivals have irregular demonyms, *-ese* adjectivals used as demonyms sound old-fashioned ("He is a Chinese"), and others are truly exceptional: *French* to *French[wo]man*, etc.

[See adjectivals and demonyms for nations.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjectivals_and_demonyms_for_countries_and_nations)

Comment: In [an article linked to the one you cited](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternative_words_for_British#Other_languages), it notes how “[i]n French, the word britannique (‘British’) is restricted to more official contexts and tends to be used for governments rather than for individuals.” This is the same in Spanish, where *británico* is little used, and when it is, tends to apply more to governments than people. As with French *anglais*, [the Spanish normally just use *inglés* in regular speech](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reino_Unido#Etimolog.C3.ADa).

Answer (score 0):

'Ancient Britons' is a recognised term in history and archaeology referring to the original inhabitants.

*Brits* is used but can often have negative associations, eg the Brits behaving badly abroad, getting into drunken fights with football supporters. I would always refer to someone as British and not a Brit or Briton.

Other countries have a similar adjectival word but for some reason adding 'man' or 'woman' doesn't sound as clumsy eg Frenchman. The individual countries of the UK will happily call their citizens an English/Irish/Scots/Welshman/woman but I pretty sure I've never seen Britishman/woman written all as one word.

Which still leaves and unsatisfactory gap if you wanted to say  - "I shared a car with a German, an Australian and a ....?"

Comment: Well, you *could* call him an Englishman, a Scot, or a Welshman. The Manx and Channel Islanders probably have to fend for themselves, though.

Comment: @tchrist. Only in cases where the passenger was male. Even _a Scot_ suggests the presence of large quantities of testosterone.

Comment: I don’t perceive any such negative association with _a Brit_. It’s a perfectly neutral word for me, to the same extent that _an American_ is. Americans abroad have plenty of bad rep, but saying that you shared a car with an American is perfectly neutral. I doubt the Brit Awards consider their name particularly negative, either.