# Why can we say 'an American' but not 'a British'?

Tags: nouns, adjectives, articles, indefinite-articles, demonyms

I am confused with the use of an indefinite article in front of *British* or *Chinese*. 
To my understanding, we can place an indefinite article in front of any “countable noun”. 
So, we can say *a cup* and *an orange*.

But when it comes to nationalities, it is very confusing. For example, we can say *an American* or *a German*. But we cannot say *a British* or *a Chinese*.

I looked them up in a dictionary as at first I thought *British* and *Chinese* are adjectives in the above statement and that is why we cannot place an article in front of it.

However, the dictionary mentions that they are nouns.  Does that mean they are uncountable nouns?

Comment: Related question: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/96894/for-people-can-you-say-a-british-like-you-can-say-an-australian

Comment: Your dictionary is wrong.

Comment: Others have given some explanations. But the answer to _why_ this is so, like almost all "why" questions about language, is "Because that's the way English is".

Comment: Also related: [Americans can eat Chinese, but Chinese can’t eat Americans?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/163195/americans-can-eat-chinese-but-chinese-cant-eat-americans)

Comment: wouldn't you say a Briton? right?

Comment: because Scots would get angry

Answer (score 84):

The noun for an inhabitant of Britain is *Briton*.
*British* is an adjective.

For many countries, the adjective and noun are identical.  As you've found, *German* and *American* are good examples.

The noun for an inhabitant of China has historically been *Chinaman* but in recent times, the word *Chinese* has been increasingly used.

Comment: Or sometimes 'Brit', if you are American.

Comment: Hasn't _Chinaman_ become pejorative?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16920/discussion-on-answer-by-chenmunka-why-can-we-say-an-american-but-not-a-britis).

Comment: I don't know who approved of this edit, but I wouldn't have. I fully agree with [@Colin Fine's](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/194684/why-can-we-say-an-american-but-not-a-british/194686#comment408781_194686) observation.

Comment: @Mari-LouA The reasoning behind my edit: The issue of *chinaman*'s offensiveness is clearly inflammatory and without consensus, so I killed the issue altogether; now datedness is all that's implied. Any word's (non-?)offensiveness is completely irrelevant to this question. Does that seem agreeable?

Comment: @Homer "[Dude, chinaman is not the preferred nomenclature. Asian-American, please.](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=OYOzUHnPJvU)"

Answer (score 39):

Your dictionary may list *British* and *Chinese* as nouns because they are used as collective nouns, to refer to the  population of each country as a whole or as a generalization:

> The British are mad about football (soccer).

Compare with

> Americans are obsessed with football (not soccer).

*The British* is really just a short form of *The British people*, with the noun presumed.  In the same way, you can say "I'll have the red" when someone asks you what type of wine you want -- the noun (wine) is presumed, so the adjective stands on its own.

Comment: People do occasionally use Chinese and Japanese as countable nouns ("A Japanese", "two Chinese" etc), but it sounds very strange to me (native, UK). I've only ever seen it written in non-fiction books or academic papers by authors aged 50+, never heard it spoken.

Comment: That's true -- as discussed in the comments to the other answer, the use of *a Chinese* has developed because the historical noun is no longer considered politically correct.  However, the same can't be said for *a British*; I'm pretty sure that if a dictionary is listing *British* as a noun, it is the collective use that is being referenced.

Answer (score 13):

The problem is that sometimes there is an easily available adjective form but not an easily available noun form.

This is also complicated by the fact that we can form a collective noun from an adjective by adding the definite article, such as *the rich* or *the famous*. Now *British*, *English* and *Welsh* are adjectives, and we can certainly talk about *the British*, *the English* and *the Welsh*. We cannot however say *a British*, *an English* or *a Welsh* because the proper noun forms are different. We need to say *a Briton* (or *a Brit*, as noted by Erik), *an Englishman* or *an Englishwoman* and *a Welshman* or *a Welshwoman*.

There are other instances when the adjective form and the noun form are identical: you have already noted *American* and *German*. Other examples are *Italian*, *African*, *Israeli*, *Indonesian*, *Pakistani*, *Indian* and *Brazilian*. You might note that many in this category end with *-an* or *-i*. This might be useful as a rule of thumb for adjectives that can be used as nouns too.

Comment: Polish, Swedish, Finish, Turkish, Danish etc are like English (with nouns Pole, Swede, Finn, Turk, Dane, etc). The -ish formation seems to be older and looks Anglo-Saxon to me.

Comment: So is it true that all -ish nationality adjectives (and similar variteties, like French) can't be used as countable nouns, but all other nationality adjectives can? If so, that'd be a handy rule (but I'd be surprised if it's that simple...). I can't think of any exceptions.

Comment: I can't think of an exception either. The rule also applies to Scottish, Irish, Flemish, Cornish, Spanish and even Wendish, Lettish and Rhenish which are rather less often used. Also Manx.

Comment: Yes, I think today -_ish_ adjectives are like -_ese_ adjectives (Japanese, Portuguese, Sinhalese).

Comment: "A Brit" may be used in some places, but it is no more the correct term for an inhabitant of the UK  than "a Yank" is  for an inhabitant of the USA.

Answer (score 8):

I upvoted @Chanmunka's answer, but let me add an additional thought that's too long to fit in a comment:

Yes, the usage is inconsistent, or at least appears inconsistent.

For some nationalities, the noun for a person from that place and the adjective for that place are the same. "Bob is an American. Bob drives an American car." "Erwin is a German. Erwin drives a German car."

For others the words are different. "Richard is a Briton." But, "Richard drives a British car."

Oh, and by the way, often you make the adjective by dropping any final vowel and adding -an to the noun. Like *America* -> *American, Mexico* -> *Mexican, Venezuela* -> *Venezuelan, Russia* -> *Russian.* If it ends in *-y* you change the *-y* to an *-i-*: *Italy* -> *Italian.* But for some reason *Canada* does not become "Canadan" but *Canadian.* Other times we drop the final syllable and add *-ish.* Like *Britain* -> *British, Poland* -> *Polish, Ireland* -> *Irish.* And then there are always the weird cases, like *Netherlands* becomes not "Netherlandan" or "Netherish" but *Dutch.*

For many nations the convention used to be that we used the adjective plus *-man* or the name of the place plus *-man* to refer to a person from that country. "Francois is a Frenchman." "Li is a Chinaman." Etc. As the conversation on another post indicated, some now consider that sexist, but no clear alternative has become accepted, so we're rather stuck using a phrase, "Francois is from France" or "Francois is a French person."

When the adjective is different from the noun, you can use "the" plus the adjective to describe the people of that nation as a whole. "The British like to drink tea." "The Chinese built the Great Wall." When the adjective is the same as the noun, you use the plural to describe that nation as a whole. "Germans are hard-working people." "Italians are crazy." Etc.

Comment: “A German” sounds decidedly clunky and, erm, acidifluous (‽) to my ear. Cases like “a German” or “a French” are most commonly just avoided altogether: as such, I would always say, “He is German/French/etc.” using the adjective instead of the noun—even in most cases where the adjective can do double duty. The only ones I can think of where “He is a [double-duty noun/adjective]” doesn't sound clunky and unnatural are ones in _-an_: American, Australian, Mexican, etc. Not all of those work either: Canadian, German, Belgian, etc.

Comment: Americans, at least, routinely say that someone is "a German" or "a Canadian". We most definitely do not say "a French", but rather "a French person" or "from France". Maybe usage in other English-speaking countries is different.

Comment: I'm not sure of your correspondence between Netherlands and Dutch - I have been corrected in the past by Friesians (from Friesland, part of the Netherlands) that "Dutch" refers specifically to Holland (another part of the Netherlands), and it as insulting to call a citizen of Friesland (or Gelderland, or Zeeland, etc.) "Dutch" as it is to call a Scotsman "English". Map of Netherlands here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netherlands#mediaviewer/File:Netherlands_Map.svg

Comment: @grimxn Yes, I've heard that too, didn't go into it as it was a side note on the main subject. I think 99.9% of Americans would call anyone from the Netherlands "Dutch", and to the best of my knowledge we have no more general term. Happy to hear if anyone has more information on this.

Comment: @Jay, which leaves us with the question - what is the adjective from Netherlands? :)

Comment: @grimxn Yeah, that's my point. At least for the Scottish question, we have a general word: "British". For the Netherlands, to the best of my knowledge, we don't, and so we use Dutch for all of them. BTW reminds me of a World War 2 movie I saw years ago, where a representative from the military is sent to tell a family that their son has been killed in action. He tries to console them by saying, "He died fighting for England." And the father replies harshly, "He was Scottish." Leaving the army guy stammering.

Comment: @Grimxn: The OED lists [Netherlandian](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/126303) (rare), [Netherlandic](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/126304) and [Netherlandish](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/126305) as possible adjectives.  The latter is also a noun (for the language spoken in the Netherlands, with [Netherlander](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/126302) being another noun for the natives thereof).

Comment: In the United States, at least, the term "Chinaman" is archaic, and even mildly pejorative, given the second-class citizenship conferred on Asians (and let's face it, all non-white males) until relatively recently.

Comment: @EricLloyd I agree that "Chinaman" is archaic, and that some view it as pejorative. Exactly why is hard to say. The Irish were discriminated against at one time too, and no one says that "Irish" is pejorative. Nor is "Chinese" considered pejorative. Exactly what makes one word derogatory and another complimentary is not at all clear to me. But whatever, not the main point here.

Answer (score 3):

It's a question of plurality.

"An American" signifies an individual whose is a citizen of the United States of America.  To signify the entire populations, you'd say "Americans".

"British" signifies the entire population of the United Kingdom.  An individual would be referred to as a [Briton](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/Briton).